# Passing ArrayList from Fragment class to Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have main fragment   and I want to pass `ArrayList` to `Activity` class, where I will show the result in ListView.

Fragment class:

```
public class StudentActivity extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
}
```

I have data

```
ArrayList<> allStudents = new ArrayList();
allStudents.add(new Student("H", 99, 93) );    
allStudents.add(new Student("C", 98, 92) );
allStudents.add(new Student("B", 98, 91) );    
allStudents.add(new Student("A", 80, 94) );
allStudents.add(new Student("F", 70, 84) );
```

Now I want to send "allStudents" object to new activity class StudentResult();

I am using in fragment class:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), StudentResult.class);
intent.putExtra("ExtraData", allStudents);
startActivity(intent);
```

and in target class to show the objects in ListView();

```
public class ResultActivity extends Activity {

    public void myData(ArrayList<allStudents> myArray) {
    marjslistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<allStudents>(this, R.layout.student_list, myArray);
    ...
    ScoreLV.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    ...
    }
}
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: *ArrayList<>* the diamond operator is not available in Android

Comment: "public class StudentActivity extends Fragment"

That can't be right.

Comment: Read the article http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html and you will understand how organize activity <-> fragment communations.

Comment: where have you reached with this ? would appreciate if you reply :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an custom interface in your Fragment:

```
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {    
    public void onFragmentSetStudents(ArrayList<Student>);         
}
```

Implement this interface in your Activity:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements YourFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
   private ArrayList<Student> allStudents;
}
```

Now you have to override the declared method (in your `Activity`):

```
@Override
public void onFragmentSetStudents(ArrayList<Student> students) {
  allStudents = students;
}
```

Then you just have to start this method with an Listener in your Fragment:

```
OnFragmetInteractionListener listener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
listener.onFragmentStudents(allStudents)
```

Comment: correction : `public void onFragmentSetStudents(ArrayList<Student> students); `

Answer (score 1):

In your `Activity`:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras(); 
ArrayList allStudents = bundle.get("ExtraData");
```

and I think you need to define your `ArrayAdapter` as:

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Student>(this, R.layout.student_list, allStudents);
```

You have the rest of the code, just add the above. It should work.

Comment: @carebro: the previous worked but your also perfect ! but I can't answer two of them