# Not able to Pass Array of object in a new activity

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am showing a listview in one fragment "Recent" based on user input. Now, I want to pass that listview as array of objects to container activity (Main Activity) (I am using interface to pass data) and then when user click a button in MainActivity, that arraylist get passed to another activity where it will again be shown as ListView. When I am running application it is showing error "Application is stopped". In logcat also, no error is shown.Please Help.

```
1. My relevant code of interface in Fragment:


        @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);                mListView=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.myListView);

              placeList.add(new Place("Shoppers Stop (1st Floor)", "Get 10% Off on Clothes & Jewellery", "shop1"));
                                    placeList.add(new Place("Dominos (2nd Floor)", "Get 10% Off on Chef Special Pizzas", "shop2"));
                                    placeList.add(new Place("More MegaStore (3rd Floor)", "Wednesday Bazaar, Get min 10% Off","shop4"));
                          mPlaces=placeList.toArray(new Place[placeList.size()]);//Convert arraylist to array
                          passData(mPlaces);//Pass Array of objects for interface


            mPlaceAdapter = new PlaceAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row, mPlaces);

                            if (mListView != null) {
                                mListView.setAdapter(mPlaceAdapter);\\Creating listview in fragment
                            }

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
                return view;
            }


    //Inetrface definition
         public interface OnDataPass {
                public void onDataPass(Place[] data);
            }

            OnDataPass dataPasser;

            @Override
            public void onAttach(Context context) {
                super.onAttach(context);
                dataPasser = (OnDataPass) context;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDetach() {
                super.onDetach();
                dataPasser=null;
            }

            public void passData(Place[] data) {
                dataPasser.onDataPass(data);
            }
        }

        2. Main Activity (Container of fragement):
      @Override
        public void onDataPass(Place []data) {

            Collections.addAll(allOffers,data);

        }


            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

                switch(item.getItemId()){
                            case R.id.all:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AllOffersActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("AllOffers", (ArrayList<Place>)allOffers);
                        getApplication().startActivity(intent);
                        return true;
                            default: return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

                }

            }

    3. AllOffersActivity Class (where again I want to show listviews):


                        @Override
                        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                            setContentView(R.layout.activity_alloffers);
                          onePlaces=(ArrayList<Place>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("AllOffers");
                            if(onePlaces!=null) {
                                mPlaces = onePlaces.toArray(new Place[onePlaces.size()]);//To store data into an array 

                            }

                            allPlaceAdapter = new PlaceAdapter(AllOffersActivity.this, R.layout.row, mPlaces);
                            allListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.allListView);

                            if (allListView != null) {
                                allListView.setAdapter(allPlaceAdapter);
                            }

                        }
                    }

    4. AndroidManifest.xml:

        <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                    </intent-filter>
         </activity>

                <activity android:name=".activity.AllOffersActivity"/>
```

5. Images-i) Image to show listview in fragment and when user clicks "star" icon at bottom, new activity should show listview which is getting shown in fragment

Comment: How do you pass the places from one activity to the other activity? Could you append the soucecode for this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps to pass an array of user defined objects.

**Step 1 :** `public class Place implements Serializable`

**Step 2:** Modify the following in your activity where you are passing the data to other class

```
Intent data = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AllOffersActivity.class);
data.putExtras("AllOffers", (Serializable) allOffers);
startActivity(data);
```

**Step 3:** In receiving class

```
if(getIntent() != null) {
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("AllOffers");
}
```

Try this.

Comment: putSerializable is showing red in code and saying method not resolved. How to correct it.

Comment: I have changed my code. Please have a look. Hope this helps.

Comment: this same technique also works for `Fragment.setArguments` since it takes a `Bundle`.

Comment: Thanks Solved my issue. I already tried with putExtras and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**You can Use Bundle to pass array object from one fragment to other activity**

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

bundle.putStringArray(mMyList, "my_list_key");

fragment.setArguments(bundle);

or  [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082950/passing-arraylist-from-fragment-class-to-activity)

Comment: Hi Thanks for sharing the link. I have a doubt in one of code there.OnFragmetInteractionListener listener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;  What is this activity?

Comment: `putStringArray` only works for `ArrayList<String>` not `ArrayList<Object>`.  You must use a `Serializable` class and pass that.  also note all sub-objects of that must also be `Serializable`.

Comment: Yes, using serializable solved my issue. Thanks a lot

Comment: its interface for sharing data you can make it anywhere @escape-llc