# Passing Arraylist from fragment to Activity

Tags: android-activity, arraylist

I have got an arraylist with values in a fragment and I want to return that arraylist to the activity to display the contents of the list. What shall be the easiest approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data between a fragment and its container activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343241/passing-data-between-a-fragment-and-its-container-activity)

Comment: Here the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082950/passing-arraylist-from-fragment-class-to-activity